# How can i use preg_replace_callback to make the matches (bold)

Tags: php, regex

im trying to find a way to use preg_replace_callback to replace the matches with `<b>` match   `</b>`

for example :

the text :

> This is a text ,, text , this is a text

the pattern

> /text/   or    /(text)/  or any pattern which can find text

i want the result is:

> This is a `<b>`text`</b>` ,, `<b>`text`</b>` , this is a `<b>`text`</b>`

Thanks..

Comment: Did you try to write a callback function yet?

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean something like

```
(\btext\b)
```

and replace it with

```
<b> $1 <\b>
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2u5km)

I don't think that you need `preg_replace_callback`, you can use backreferences with `preg_replace` that should be enough for what you want.

You can do something like

```
$string = 'This is a text ,, text , this is a text';
$pattern = '/(\btext\b)/';
$replacement = '<b> $1 <\b>';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

See the [preg_replace doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: Oh, sorry i dont mean this ,, i mean (The user is enter the pattern not me). so he maybe didnt put the pattern between () ,, i mean . i want to get all matches , and replace each match with same match but between two html tags i mean `<b>` and `</b>` .

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with:

```
<?php
$search = 'test';
$text = 'This is a test string';
// Filter out unwanted junk
$search = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]/', '', $search);
echo preg_replace('/('.$search.')/i', '<b>\1</b>', $text);
?>
```

This would produce:

```
This is a <b>test</b> string
```

Comment: Oh, sorry i dont mean this ,, i mean (The user is enter the pattern not me). so he maybe didnt put the pattern between () ,, i mean . i want to get all matches , and replace each match with same match but between two html tags i mean `<b>` and `</b>`

Comment: Oh,Thanks , sorry its also not what i want ,, i cant describe what i want , but you can help me by giving me a code to make the matches between <b> tags ,, (USING PREG_REPLACE_CALLBACK) i mean with a function ,, sorry for questions ,, thanks .

Comment: Thank you, i got it , the working code is echo preg_replace_callback($patt,create_function(
    '$matches','return "<b>" . $matches[0] . "</b>";'
    ),$text);

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this.

```
$string = "This is a text ,, text , this is a text";
$string = str_replace("text","<b>text</b>",$string);
```

Its very easy way, less confusion :)